# MySQL select row by searching in array field, and if value found, select that row

Tags: php, mysql

Have issue by selecting rows. Have field `location_ids` and it has value for example - `["13", "5", "25"]` . I want to search in that field and if it founds number 13 for example it select a row

I found that it could be done with `FIND_IN_SET` function but it didn't work for me `SELECT * FROM staffs WHERE FIND_IN_SET(13, locations_ids)`

Maybe it could be done with JSON functions?

Thanks for answers

Comment: sounds like you should have normalized your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regexp in this case. This is sth i use for searching in json contained columns. It would work in your case, as well.

```
WHERE locations_ids REGEXP '[[:<:]]13[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

`FIND_IN_SET(13, locations_ids)` would work, if the `locations_ids` would be `'13, 5, 25'`. But with your format you can use

```
JSON_CONTAINS(location_ids, '"13"')
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/HLLY47255

Note that neither of the two ways can use an index for a fast search. With a normalized schema your query could be:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM staffs s
JOIN staffs_locations sl ON sl.staff_id = s.id
WHERE sl.location_id = 13;
```

And this would return the result almost instantly even with millions of rows (if propper indexes are defined).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just reformat the array and use IN?

```
SELECT * 
FROM staffs 
WHERE locations_ids in (13,5,25)
```

If locations_ids contains  *["13", "5", "25"]*, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM staffs
WHERE locations_ids like '%"13"%'
```

Comment: I can't reformat field values. And I have only one number for example 5 and I need to find row that has that number in field location_ids.

Comment: So the column locations_ids contains the square bracketed list?